# 'sp_releaseschemalock' causing me a blocking issue?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, blocking

why 'sp_releaseschemalock' causing me a blocking issue? 
what proccess that must execute sp_releaseschemalock or what function of sp_releaseschemalock?

I have searched various forums or blogs about the explanation of the sp_releaseschemalock but have not found a proper explanation. what sp_releaseschemalock do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp_releaseschemalock` is an undocumented external proc which simply releases the schema lock:

As per our past experience on this, we witnessed the same but never had the issue with `sp_releaseschemalock` being a culprit.

Kindly check the complete details when checking the blocking. That is ,you should not completely ignore the one that is getting blocked rather than completely dependent on blkd_by_spid, as blkd_by shows sp_releaseschemalock as culprit.

Also would like you to refer [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic306282-5-1.aspx)

> You should check your linked server configurations and make sure they
>   are "collation compatible" checked. Otherwise the entire remote table
>   is returned to the local calling server to execute the WHERE clause.

As mentioned, you need to go through the settings for the query getting executed via linked server because the primary server wont have the required statistical information when fetching the same from other server through its linked query.

Comment: for linked server configuration(collation compatible) has been checked(True), but the problem of blocking by sp_releaseschemalock still occur. I was intrigued by your statement about "primary server wont have the required statistical information when fetching the same from other servers through its linked query". please explain about the concept of fetching the data thus 'required statistical information'

Answer (score 1):

for linked server configuration(collation compatible) has been checked(True), but the problem of blocking by sp_releaseschemalock still occur. I was intrigued by your statement about "primary server wont have the required statistical information when fetching the same from other servers through its linked query". please explain about the concept of fetching the data thus 'required statistical information'